# tool to create from plain html file a .po file used for translation

Tags: json, localization, po

i am using the http://i18next.com/ to translate a static website hosted on github gh-pages.

are there any tools that i can use to first extract from say the index.html file and create a index.po file where the translator can localize / internationalize the page and then use a tool like http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pojson to convert this po file to json to be used by i18next?

Answer (score 0):

POEdit will probably do the trick. In PHP, the Gettext extension (http://es.php.net/gettext) will help. Also, I found this link that will detail the process of creating a po file: http://www.wdmac.com/how-to-create-a-po-language-translation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [po4a](https://po4a.org/index.php.en) for creating po files from html and from many other formats.